# What is the use of FileSystem API in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-filesystem

Are there any use cases of using File System API in Firefox? [All examples on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_API) show savePicker functions that are not supported by Firefox. Can you use this API for something useful or is it useless in Firefox?

I've found [requestFileSystem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestFileSystem) but it's deprecated and not supported by Firefox.

I want to play with the API and maybe create FS library or extension to [lightning-fs](https://github.com/isomorphic-git/lightning-fs) for usage with [isomorphic-git](https://isomorphic-git.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I was searching more and found this Reddit post from 3 years ago:

[Will firefox support the file system access API?](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/lnknvk/will_firefox_support_the_file_system_access_api/)

that links to [this statement](https://mozilla.github.io/standards-positions/#native-file-system)

> There's a subset of this API we're quite enthusiastic about (in particular providing a read/write API for files and directories as alternative storage endpoint), but it is wrapped together with aspects for which we do not think meaningful end user consent is possible to obtain (in particular cross-site access to the end user's local file system). Overall we consider this harmful therefore, but Mozilla could be supportive of parts, provided this were segmented better.

So it's most likely that FileSystem will never be implemented in Firefox. Evnt that part of the API is available. Without the pickers functions, you can't access the file system and save the files locally.